# Fastest iOS data format for parsing

Tags: ios, xml, json, parsing, csv

I am in need of a data format which will allow me to reduce the time needed to parse it to a minimum. In other words I'm looking for a format with as little overhead as possible and being parseable in the shortest amount of time.

I am building an application which will pull a lot of data from an API, parse it and display it to the user. So the format should be as small as possible so that the transmission will be fast and also should be very efficient for parsing. What are my options?

Here are a few formats that pop in in my head:

- XML (a lot of overhead and slow parsing IMO)
- JSON (still too cumbersome)
- [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org) (looks interesting)
- CSV (with a custom parser written in C)
- Plist (fast parsing, a lot of overhead)
- ... any others?

So currently I'm looking at CSV the most. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Each data item has approximately 2 or 3 value string and 2 or 3 labels (20 characters or less). So around 60 characters per item. Currently it looks like there will be up to 10000 items per call so that is not very much. But it is possible that calls will be subsequent with as little as 1 second between each so I'd like it to be fast and responsive.

Comment: JSON is fast, human readable, and standard. Parser built into iOS. But what you describe looks like you want CoreData.

Comment: Core data is a storage interface, I need to pull some data from the API and parse it into ObjC constructs such as `NSNumber`, `NSDate` and `NSString` which are then usable for displaying, storing or whatever.

Comment: The volume you describe (up to a continuous 5mbps) might suggest a protocol other than repeatedly fetching data. Maybe sockets or some other streaming protocol. It's hard to say on the basis of what's provided thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Apple in [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html) binary plist representation should be fastest

> Property List Representations
>
> A property list can be stored in one of three different ways: in an
>   XML representation, in a binary format, or in an “old-style” ASCII
>   format inherited from OpenStep. You can serialize property lists in
>   the XML and binary formats. The serialization API with the old-style
>   format is read-only.
>
> XML property lists are more portable than the binary alternative and
>   can be manually edited, but binary property lists are much more
>   compact; as a result, they require less memory and can be read and
>   written much faster than XML property lists. In general, if your
>   property list is relatively small, the benefits of XML property lists
>   outweigh the I/O speed and compactness that comes with binary property
>   lists. If you have a large data set, binary property lists, keyed
>   archives, or custom data formats are a better solution.

You just need to set the correct flag while creation or reading  `NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0`. Just be sure that the data you want to represent in the plist are resented by this format.

Comment: Are they actually faster than CSV with C language parsing? Do you have any additional documentation here? Sounds promising.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I also remember in one of the earliest WWDC video that an Apple engineer was showing a sort of compare between different parsing method. I don't remember if CSV was one them. You can do a benchmark and update the answer with results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518215/whats-faster-on-iphone-xml-plist-or-json here they mention the WWDC video